# Intersection Observer Scrolling Problem On Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, reactjs, intersection-observer

I'm having trouble with Intersection Observer in Gatsbyjs.

**There is a fixed header that needs to change the color when some section enters 90% of the viewport.**

I've created a component called **IntersectionObserverComponent** that renders a div with absolute position and height of 100vh. The idea is to include this component into a section that I want to track with Intersection Observer.

Here's my component

```
class IntersectionObserverComponent extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    //
    this.observer = null
    this.ref = React.createRef()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { root, threshold, callback } = this.props

    ('IntersectionObserver' in window
      ? Promise.resolve()
      : import('intersection-observer')
    ).then(() => {
      this.observer = new IntersectionObserver(
        entries => {
          entries.forEach(entry => {
            callback(entry)
          })
        },
        { threshold, root }
      )

      if (this.ref.current) {
        this.observer.POLL_INTERVAL = 100
        this.observer.observe(this.ref.current)
      }
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.ref.current && this.observer) {
      this.observer.unobserve(this.ref.current)
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.ref}
        style={{
          height: '100vh',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 0,
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
        }}
      ></div>
    )
  }
}

export default IntersectionObserverComponent
```

And here's the usage

```
import { handleHeaderStyle } from '../../utils/intersectionObserver'

const About = ({ isTrackable = false, handleChangeHeader = () => {} }) => {
  // previousValues object is directly mutated in a handleHeaderStyle fn
  const previousValues = { previousY: 0, previousRatio: 0 }
  const colors = { prevColor: 'white', currColor: 'secondary' }

  const handleIOCallback = entry => {
    console.log(entry)
    handleHeaderStyle(entry, colors, previousValues, handleChangeHeader)
  }

  return (
    <section className="padding-top-m padding-bottom-tablet-portrait-96 header-behind background-gray-small-only">
      {isTrackable ? <IO callback={handleIOCallback} /> : null}

      <Container>
        <Grid className="grid-padding-x">
          <Cell small={12} large={8}>
            <p className="margin-bottom-small-20 margin-bottom-tablet-portrait-32">
              We are a brand and product development consultancy, that believes
              in that design is essentially a problem-solving exercise that we
              can apply to any sector, discipline or media.
            </p>
            <p className="margin-bottom-small-32">
              We are founded on and by people who are driven by:
            </p>
            <ul className="arrow-bullets">
              <li>
                Crafting simple and notable components that build up your
                brand’s value
              </li>
              <li>Discovery and research aimed at thoughtful practices</li>
              <li>Attention to detail</li>
              <li>Independence and creative freedom</li>
              <li>Thinking that goes deeper</li>
            </ul>
          </Cell>
          <Cell className="padding-top-m">
            <Projects />
          </Cell>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </section>
  )
}

export default About
```

And here's the function that handles logic for updating header

```
export const handleHeaderStyle = (
  IOEntry,
  colors,
  previousValues,
  callback
) => {
  if (!IOEntry || !colors || !previousValues || typeof callback !== 'function')
    return
  //
  const { prevColor, currColor } = colors
  const currentY = IOEntry.boundingClientRect.y
  const currentRatio = IOEntry.intersectionRatio
  const isIntersecting = IOEntry.isIntersecting

  // going up
  if (currentY > previousValues.previousY) {
    if (currentRatio < previousValues.previousRatio && !isIntersecting) {
      callback(prevColor)
    }
  }
  // going down
  else if (currentY < previousValues.previousY && isIntersecting) {
    if (currentRatio > previousValues.previousRatio) {
      callback(currColor)
    }
  }

  previousValues.previousY = currentY
  previousValues.previousRatio = currentRatio
}
```

This is working really nice on all screen sizes when I test it in a desktop browser but the problem occurs when I test it on an actual mobile device.

- Device: Iphone 7+, IOS 13.3.1
- Browsers: Safari 12.1.1, Chrome 80

It works great if I don't release my finger while scrolling, but If I do, the callback is not fired consistently. I've also tried setting the POLL_INTERVAL to 100ms but it didn't help.

I'm suspecting that has something to do with the way iOS Safari handles the scroll event (https://github.com/martinlaxenaire/curtainsjs/issues/18)

Here's the test link on Netlify - https://nifty-einstein-c4cf08.netlify.com/

I'm trying to figure it out for days now, thanks in advance

Comment: Having the same problem. @Andrija Pavlovic, were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?